# Power BI - Dashboard vs Reports

Tags: powerbi, report, dashboard

I have pinned my report from Power BI to a dashboard in Power BI. I was wondering, if I was on the dashboard, can I switch between bookmarks? I'm trying to click on my button to switch to another bookmark but it doesn't do anything. The bookmarks are both within the same report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your bookmarks don't work on a dashboard, but you can goto [Bookmarks on BI Service at Dashboard level](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31942489-bookmarks-on-bi-service-at-dashboard-level) to vote for an implementation.